# export works in command line but not in a bash script

Tags: shell, unix, variables

I tried to write a script in order to automate the switching between php5.3 and 5.4 in my path. Although the export works when I execute it, it does nothing when it runs inside the script.

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
# chphp
# Switch between php versions 5.3 and 5.4

FIXED_PATH=/here/is/my/path

if [ "$1" != "-v" ]
then
    echo "Wrong usage of the script.\n"
else
    if [ "$2" == 3 ]
    then
            export PATH="$FIXED_PATH:/path/to/php-5.3/bin"
            export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=""
    elif [ "$2" == 4 ]
    then
            export PATH="$FIXED_PATH:/path/to/php-5.4/bin"
            export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR="/path/to/php-5.4/etc/php-dbg.d"
    else
            echo "Wrong usage of the script.\n"
    fi
fi
```

I also tried the following, which I found by searching for similar questions, but they didn't work

this

```
. ./chphp.sh -v 3
```

and this

```
source ./chphp.sh -v 3
```

Any suggestions or ideas how I could fix it or do things differently?

EDIT: The code was missing an else after the first echo, as Kent noticed and which I edited. The code now runs with both ways now!

Comment: your script expects 2 arguments, did you notice that?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, unfortunately I forgot to type it in the question. Now it is editied.

Comment: As @Kent noticed I had a mistake in my if statement. With the . ./chphp.sh -v 3  command it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your script will set vars only if `$1` is **NOT** `-v`

if `$1` is `-v`, your script does nothing. check your script the first `if-then`

does this help? (to set php5.3 stuffs)

```
source ./chphp.sh foo 3
```

Comment: You are right. I think that my eyes are tired. I was planning to put the part of code after the first echo in the else. Thanks for the help :)